# How to set Oracle ClientId field in nHibernate?

Tags: asp.net, oracle, nhibernate, database-connection

Through the use of nHibernate library, is there a way to set the Oracle ClientId off of the connection object? If nHibernate does not support the setting of the ClientId field, what can I do to assign a custom string to my Oracle connection object obtained from nHibernate? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The connection is available as session.Connection.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a class that inherits from `DriverConnectionProvider` and overrides `GetConnection()`. There you can modify the `IDbConnection` object. Of course you also need to configure this class in the NHibernate SessionFactory configuration, for example in hibernate.cfg.xml.